# PyAutoGUI how to define color range

Tags: python, colors, click, pyautogui

How do define a color range in PyAutoGUI?
My code looks like this

```
for i in range(loop):
        if (pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(782, 435, (110, 78, 59))):
            continue
        elif (pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(782, 435, (color range here))):
            continue
        else:
            pyautogui.click(x=782, y=435)
```

I want it to click if 110, 78, 59 is false and the color range is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tolerance` argument.

```
for i in range(loop):
    if not (pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(782, 435, (110, 78, 59), tolerance = 10)):
        pyautogui.click(x=782, y=435)
```

The `tolerance` argument specifies, how much the rgb-values of the color are allowed to vary from the rgb-values passed into the function.

Comment: Didn't think of that! It still doesn't work, however. My the colour (183, 77, 170) fades into the background colour (110, 78, 59) so it still clicks no matter how low tolerance I put. I tried as low as 0.000001, and it still did not work so I suspect it caps it to 1.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "fading into the background"? Is it animated? Or just a static image? If it is static, you can take a screenshot and take the exact at the wanted pixel, that you wish to check for. If you have a fade in a timed animation, then you could check constantly for one color and once it's found, check for example 1 second after, for the color, that it fades to in that duration. To get exact RGB values i would use screenshots. Also: if you want a range of colors you would usually set the tolerance higher, rather than as low as possible. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I searched for the colour, added a delay then checked again so it didn't click anyways. Thanks